# how to compute the length of a curve in depth image?

Tags: opengl, curve

I am working on a project to calculate the length of any two clicked horizontal points in depth image. My Platform is visual studio 2013 and OpenGL. Following is the steps:

1. Find all horizontal points between the 2 points in depth image;
2. compute every 2 points length in the found points, and sum all the interval length, then get curve length. Interval value is 1.

However, I found the length by this method is shorter than real length. Who would be kind to tell me what's problem and which method I should adopt?

Note: line length between any 2 points(not so close)is right.

Comment: Do i get you right, that you are walking pixel by pixel through your depth image, compute the 3d-coordinate of every pixel and sum up all the distances between two pixels 3d-coordinates to get a curve length? This seems a bit unsusual, but should work in general. You have to be careful to correctly compute 3d-points and of course this wont work if the curve is not completely visible (i.e. shadowed by other geometry). Also the result can only be seen as a coarse approximation. Without more information on how you compute this or an image it is hard to tell what is wrong.

Comment: thanks! You are right, I am walking pixel by pixel through depth image. You said that my method is unusual. Could you tell me what's usual method for the project. Do I need to create a 3D model on depth image first?

Comment: What seems unusual to me is that i can imagine many cases where i want to compute a curve length on a 3d geometry, but i would assume that the 3d model is known if you rendered it and then it would be more accurate to work with that model. However, from your comment you do not seem to have a (complete) model, and thus the method seems may very well be the right thing to do. If you do not have a model or want the GPU speed its perfectly okay.

Comment: After study a lot these days, I decided to make a 3D model first. My  binocular camera is based on the principle of structured light reflection. The depth value of directly facing camera is correct, but the side is error. So in order to get correct measurement result, a 3D model should be created first.